# Unable to access the this context inside the callback in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

```
import {ApiTags} from "@nestjs/swagger";
import {Body, Controller, Get, Param, Post, Res,Req} from "@nestjs/common";
import {ReceiptService} from "../service/ReceiptService";
import {ReceiptDto} from "../common/domain/ReceiptDto";
import {Response,Request} from 'express';
import {HttpService} from "@nestjs/axios";

@ApiTags('Receipt')
@Controller({version:'1',path:'Receipt'})
export class ReceiptController{
    constructor(private readonly receiptService:ReceiptService,private readonly httpService:HttpService) {
    }
    @Post()
    generateReport(@Body() receiptDto:ReceiptDto){
        return this.receiptService.getReceiptData(receiptDto.OrderId);
    }
    @Get(':OrderId')
   async displayReceipt(@Param('OrderId') orderId:number,@Res() res:Response,@Req() req:Request){
        const data=await  this.receiptService.getReceiptData(orderId);
         res.render('OrderReceipt',{orderData:data},function (err,html) {
             res.send(html).on('finish',async function (){
                const result=await this.httpService.get(`http://localhost:51971/pdfgenerator?url=localhost:4200/v1/Receipt/${orderId}`).bind(this);
                 console.log(result);
             });
         });
    }
}
```

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined   Error has been thrown on this.httpService.get() line. I don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `function` in the `res.render` callback to an arrow function to preserve the `this` context of the class.

```js
@ApiTags('Receipt')
@Controller({version:'1',path:'Receipt'})
export class ReceiptController{
    constructor(private readonly receiptService:ReceiptService,private readonly httpService:HttpService) {
    }
    @Post()
    generateReport(@Body() receiptDto:ReceiptDto){
        return this.receiptService.getReceiptData(receiptDto.OrderId);
    }
    @Get(':OrderId')
   async displayReceipt(@Param('OrderId') orderId:number,@Res() res:Response,@Req() req:Request){
        const data=await  this.receiptService.getReceiptData(orderId);
         res.render('OrderReceipt',{orderData:data}, (err,html) => {
             res.send(html).on('finish',async () => {
                const result=await this.httpService.get(`http://localhost:51971/pdfgenerator?url=localhost:4200/v1/Receipt/${orderId}`).bind(this);
                 console.log(result);
             });
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the same after changing it to arrow function.

Comment: Sorry there was another `function` in your `res.send`'s `.on` callback. I've updated the code block